# Is it necessary to lock the tilt and shift movements for each shot?

Tags: lens, tilt-shift

The Canon TS-E 17mm F/4 has large knobs for shifting and tilting the lens plus small knobs on the opposite side of the lens for locking the shift and tilt movements.

It's already tedious to setup this lens, so I am wondering **if it is necessary to tighten both locking knobs for shooting?** Or are these more for transportation like a zoom-lock?

Comment: On the 24 TS-E II, at least on my copy, both pieces are very stiff and really do not require you to lock them down for shooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for tightening the locking knobs for shooting is that the lens can potentially change its current tilt/shift settings under its own weight.

Comment: The tilt seems prone to this when rotated vertically, I did not noticed in the horizontal direction.